# Can you put Windows 10 IoT Core on Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: windows, windows-iot, pi-zero

Can you put Windows 10 IoT Core on Raspberry Pi Zero?

According to the minimum requirements specified on [the Windows IoT core page](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/IoTCore.htm) it might seem possible, but I'm not sure.

Comment: For anyone coming here for the Pi Zero W: It uses the same chip as the original Pi Zero.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, Windows 10 IoT requires the Pi 2's ARM 7 multicore chip (BCM 2836).

Comment: is this temporary, such as a lack of drivers or something like this, or is there a permanent blocker such as not meeting hardware requirements?

Comment: Maybe we should expand this to include the reason why?

Comment: @AndreiRînea Most vendors consider ARMv6 too rare or too old to support. Microsoft is not alone : See Answer 7 [here](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/features/raspberry-pi-interview-eban-upton-reveals-all)

Comment: What about the new Zero W ?

Comment: @mawg same chip same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate confirmation.  What about the [Orange Pi Zero](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepizero/) which has a H2 Quad-core Cortex-A7 H.265/HEVC 1080P ?

Comment: I don't know about the orange Pi, but the MS IOT site or the Orange Pi forums might have an answer

Comment: As of 2 days ago, it seems that that there is, or very soon will be, a new Orange Pi Win ... http://www.cnx-software.com/2017/03/13/25-orange-pi-win-development-board-to-run-windows-10-iot-and-linux-and-android/

Comment: @Mawg That is great, but remember that questions about the Orange Pi are off topic here per the sites FAQ.

Comment: Yup, I know. I figured I could slip in a questionette in a comment :-)  Then figured I might as well answer it.  I Promise to be good in future.  Interesting, though ...

Answer (score 22):

No, it won't run on Pi Zero. It's because of the hardware. The Pi zero and the first-generation Pis (BCM2835) use ARMv6. The Pi2 (BCM2836) uses ARMv7.

Windows 10 IoT Core needs ARMv7.

If I'm going to explain it to a layman, I'll say "The CPU is different".

Comment: ehhh!, why is the CPU different? or why not have a zero with the same CPU?

Comment: @eschneider ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Gene haha, that was funny